# Building new rosjava package

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to build a new ros package using rosjava. I followed the tutorial and stored my source code in the new package (i.e. /src/main/java/org/ros/reasoner/). Than I took the sample file for build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'org.ros.RosRun'

dependencies {
  compile 'ros.rosjava_core:rosjava:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

When running my gradle with "gradle build" I get the following error.

```
  :compileJava

  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

  * What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
  > Could not find group:ros.rosjava_core, module:rosjava, version:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.
    Required by:
        :rosjava_cylinder_reasoner:unspecified
```

rosjava was build according to the tutorial with gradlew install and all went right. What is wrong with my approach?

Cheers,

Markus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34139/building-new-rosjava-package/) by [Markus Eich](https://answers.ros.org/users/1686/markus-eich/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2012-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the mistake. According to the gradle manual, a repository had to be set. I added

```
repositories {
   mavenLocal()
   maven {
     url 'http://robotbrains.hideho.org/nexus/content/groups/ros-public'
   }
 }
```

and now it can find the dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [Markus Eich](https://answers.ros.org/users/1686/markus-eich/) with karma: 202 on 2012-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0